What is the best way to query pocketbase for concurrent requests?
Currently in my application I am following the below flow to get the data each time,

Login with a pocketbase client using 'Admin email' and 'Password'.
Get the data using pocketbase client.
Logout from the pocketbase client.

Is there a better way so that i can forever query from my pocketbase client, Without logging in and out multiple times?
export const loader = async () => {
  try {
    let authData = await pb.admins.authWithPassword(process.env.POCKETBASE_EMAIL as string, process.env.POCKETBASE_PASS as string);
    const companyRecords = await pb.collection(about).getFirstListItem('') as CompanyData
    pb.authStore.clear()
    return defer({ companies: companyRecords });
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
  return { companies: null}
}
  
};

Maybe some method that is better suited when concurrent request come through my page. I cannot keep logging in and out parallelly.
